# MySQL - Visual Studio Express 2013 Issue

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to connect to a MySQL database through Visual Studio Express for Web 2013.

I have done a heap of reading about it and understand that its not easy for Express to connect with MySQL but it can be done manually.

I have redone a website in ASP from its Original PHP version that was done a while ago by someone else.
I have the connection string from the PHP document which reads

```
"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; PORT=1234; DATABASE=DB; UID=root;PASSWORD=123456789; OPTION=3"
```

So I went to the MySQL website and downloaded the ODBC connector for version 3.51 and installed it.
In my ASP.net code I have the following to get a list of tables within the database

```
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim slTables As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim sSQL As String = "select * from information_schema.tables"
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=000.000.00; PORT=1234; DATABASE=DB; UID=root;PWD=123456789"
MysqlConn.Open()
da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sSQL, MysqlConn)
da.Fill(ds)
For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    slTables.Add(dr("TABLE_NAME"))
Next
MysqlConn.Close()
```

When trying to connect I receive an authentication error regarding the username. Seeing as its both the same in the PHP and ASP connection strings, I'm not too sure why its not working. Is it something to do with not being on the Localhost server now? (I do have the actual IP address of the server).

If that's not the issue, any pointers? I'm thinking that I have either done something wrong, or that the way i'm trying to do it still cannot be done with the express version.

I have also tried using the MySQL Connector through the control panel and receive the same error.

Comment: MySql only allows connections from the local machine by default. You may need to fix this on the db server first. Also, this code is not guaranteed to close your connections, which can eventually lock you out of the DB. You should wrap your connection object in a Try/Finally block, and the easiest way to do that is with a Using block.

Comment: Your code looks like it's trying to use [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), not [MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). If you were using ODBC then you would be using an `OdbcConnection`, not a `MySqlConnection`.